# python re search syntax to identify text pattern spread over multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I recently started working with python and regular expression. As a first project, I want to read out a pdf file, filter specific text data and recombine in a excel sheet. Hence I ran in a regex problem:

**pdf file output format:**

> ...
>
> The text of this line is not always here\n
>
> The community is here to help you with **specific coding**, algorithm,
>   or language problems.**\n**
>
> **Summarize\n**
>
> **ask**\n
>
> The text of this line is not always here\n
>
> ...

I want to search for "ask" and find it by "specific coding" and "\nSummarize\n". The text below "ask" can not be used to find it reliably, because it is always different.

I tried to use (?=...) and (?<=...) for this but I couldn't figure out a suitable solution.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Has someone an idea?

Comment: You don't need the lookarounds if you use a capturing group. Try `\bspecific coding.*\s*\r?\nSummarize\s*\r?\n(ask)\b` https://regex101.com/r/dHzIx7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find `ask` you could use a capturing group instead of lookarounds. You could match `specific coding` followed by the rest of the line `.*`

If there are empty lines and newlines after it, you could use `\s*` to match those.

Then match a newline followed by `Summarize`.

Match the empty lines and a newline again and and capture `ask` in a capturing group

```
\bspecific coding\b.*\s*\r?\nSummarize\s*\r?\n(ask)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HNcxHS/1)